# Read the XML and insert into SQL Table using stored procedure If record already exist than do not insert - Only through Stored Procedure

Tags: sql

My Query :-  In this query it works only If the entire XML is parsed again, than it will not insert duplicate records , But If you change the 1 record out of 3 records in XML than it will insert all there records again, that means again duplicate records in table, Could any one please help me how can I avoid this problem, looks like I need to use cursor or for loop to traverse on each records, please help me how can i do .

This is my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_XMLtoTABLEInsert] 
(
    @xmlData XML ,
    @retValue varchar(20) OUTPUT
)
AS

    --SET @retValue =NULL;

    DECLARE @PolicyNumber VARCHAR(20) 
    DECLARE @CheckNumber VARCHAR(20) 
    DECLARE @Amount INT 

    SELECT                                                          
        @PolicyNumber=ISNULL(nref.value('PolicyNumber[1]','VARCHAR(50)'),''),                                             
        @CheckNumber=ISNULL(nref.value('CheckNumber[1]','VARCHAR(50)'),''),                                                          
        @Amount=ISNULL(nref.value('Amount[1]','int'),'')                                                                     
    FROM 
        @xmlData.nodes('tma/ tma_body / branchoperator') as R(nref)

    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from [Employee2] where PolicyNumber = @PolicyNumber and CheckNumber = @CheckNumber and Amount = @Amount)
            BEGIN
                SET @retValue='Record Already Exist';
            END

        ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from [Employee2] where PolicyNumber = @PolicyNumber and CheckNumber = @CheckNumber and Amount = @Amount)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [Employee2](PolicyNumber,CheckNumber,Amount,Collectiondate,NavDate,VendorName)
                SELECT
                    (R.ref.value('PolicyNumber[1]', 'varchar(20)')) as 'PolicyNumber',
                    R.ref.value('CheckNumber [1]', 'varchar(20)') as ' CheckNumber ',
                    R.ref.value('Amount[1]', 'int') as ' Amount',
                    R.ref.value('Collectiondate [1]', 'date') as ' Collectiondate',
                    R.ref.value('NavDate [1]', 'date') as ' NavDate',
                    R.ref.value('VendorName [1]', 'varchar(100)') as ' VendorName'
                FROM 
                    @xmlData.nodes('tma/ tma_body / branchoperator') as R(ref)

                IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0 )
                SET @retValue='SUCCESS';
            END
    END
```

Input XML-

Comment: Where's the input XML??

Comment: Thanks Marc for the response.. here is the XML - <tma>
  <tma_body>  <branchoperator>PolicyNumber>123456</PolicyNumber>
      <CheckNumber>544010844</CheckNumber><Amount>17000</Amount>
<Collectiondate>03/07/2014</Collectiondate<NavDate>03/07/2014</NavDate><VendorName>Bhadri</VendorName></branchoperator><branchoperator>  <PolicyNumber>789101</PolicyNumber>
      <CheckNumber>5477866876</CheckNumber>
      <Amount>17000</Amount>
      <Collectiondate>04/07/2014</Collectiondate>
      <NavDate>04/07/2014</NavDate>
      <VendorName>Sandeep</VendorName>
    </branchoperator>
    </tma_body>
</tma>

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.